# Generating unit php tests -> codecept.phar permission denied

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, codeception

I am trying to execute this command in console

```
test generate:test unit ClassName
```

Right after that, I get an error that says, " /Users/silversurfer/PhpstormProjects/Kalkulacka/codecept.phar generate:test unit Kalkulacka
Cannot run program "/Users/silversurfer/PhpstormProjects/Kalkulacka/codecept.phar" (in directory "/Users/silversurfer/PhpstormProjects/Kalkulacka"): error=13, Permission denied"

ClassName is "Kalkulacka"

So I guess that the codecept.phat file does not have global permission. I could not find anything about it on the internet. Could you please help me with this problem ? Thanks.
I am using PhpStorm and mac os X.

Comment: Have you tried to `chmod 755 codecept.phar` ?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.